# Pre build event in visual studio

Tags: visual-c++

Всем привет.

Есть C++ проект в Visual Studio 2012. Перед его сборкой мне необходимо выполнить pre-build event - а именно удалить определенный файл перед сборкой, другими словами мне необходимо чтобы определенный файл всегда пересобирался, даже если он не изменялся. Как я могу это сделать? В настройках проекта я хотел сделать удаление файла в Custom Build Step, но у меня не получилось так как я не знаю, что выбрать в Execute Before.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свойствах проекта Build Events, там есть события перед сборкой. Вписывайте там команду удаления файла.